# B: Yes, I have been vaccinated "with an HPV vaccine." - when the context is clear, can it be omitted?

Tags: meaning-in-context, discourse-context

**Example 1**

> A: HPV vaccines are important because they prevent women from getting cervical cancer.

(1)

> B: Yes, I have been vaccinated **with an HPV vaccine**.

(2)

> B: Yes, I have been vaccinated.

Are both (1) and (2) correct, right?

My theory is that if the context is clear, the bolded part can be omitted.

**Example 2**

> A: They cut off people once they have taken advantage of them.

(1)

> B: Yes, my friend, John, has been cut off **by him**.

(2)

> B: Yes, my friend, John, has been cut off.

Are both (1) and (2) correct, right?

My theory is that if the context is clear, the bolded part can be omitted.

Comment: I have been vaccinated **against** HPV. There are tons of vaccines. In English, we vaccinate against a disease. These are two completely different questions.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct but this relates to communication, where there is always the potential for miscommunication.

Clearer would be:

> I've had *that* vaccination.

In your second sentence, John might have been cut off by other people, not the ones mentioned earlier. Or he might have been cut off but not taken advantage of beforehand. Clearer would be:

> *That* happened to my friend.

The demonstrative adjective and demonstrative pronoun **that** refer back to the thing spoken of earlier.

But even with **that** in the second example there is a possibility that you are speaking of something that is only *similar* not identical in all respects. So if you wanted to make perfectly clear that your friend had the identical experience, the same person and the same behavior, you'd need to say so.